# Generate heatmap in Kibana?

Tags: kibana

Does anyone know of a way to generate heatmaps in Kibana?

What I'm looking for is something similar to the clusters in bettermap, but continuous (and color-coded).

Comment: Update [2015]: Heatmaps have been implemented natively in Kibana. Yay!! https://www.elastic.co/blog/kurrently-kibana-2015-05-01

Answer (score 2):

The only prerequisite is to have a geoip.location field.
If you're using an log which provide the requester origin IP you can easily get the Longitude, Latitude and then convert those values to the required geoip.coordinates field, and then the location
In kibana 4 beta:

1. open the Visualize tab
2. select tile map object
3. in the metrics value select the desired criteria from the drop down list, e.g. unique count
4. select the relevant field, e.g. hostip
5. in the buckets select Geo Coordinates
6. in the field select geoip.location
7. select the require percision (this might be important if you don't have a lot of data)
8. select the view option, you can toggle between change in color or size of circle
   [image]

BTW, if you're using logstash to send the request to elasticsearch you can use the dns filter to reverse IP to coordinates 
[logstash dns filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/dns)

Comment: Thanks, that's great, but I'm looking for a continuous 2d heatmap, maybe a bit like this http://bitly.com/1sAIxPL

Comment: @Zanbel I am new to kibana. When I select Geohash, i do not see any Fields in the drop down. What could be wrong?

Comment: @gTito - The problem is probably that the fields are not tagged correctly as geo-coordinates.
If you're using logstash to index the data you can use the following plugin (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html).

Otherwise you can create those fields yourself and it should work.

Comment: @Zanbel I am using geoip plugin. I see all the fields available in elasticsearch like country/region/area code lat/long etc. geoip {
   source => "clientIp"
   target => "geoip"
   add_tag => ['ip_processed']
   add_field => ["[geoip][coordinates]","%{[geoip][longitude]}"]
   add_field => ["[geoip][coordinates]","%{[geoip][latitude]}"]
  } - not sure what is missing.

Comment: @gTito - OK, think the problem is you are not converting the geoip field to float.
try this:
geoip {
  source => "clientip"
  target => "geoip"
  add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
  add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
}
mutate {
  convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
}

Answer (score 1):

Heatmap support for Kibana 4 is on the way - and it's looking good.

Apparently the delay is that is has to be rewritten slightly to use SVG rather than it's current approach.

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1265

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana 4, the index field has to be explicity defined as a geo_ip type in your mapping.  Kibana 3 was able to correctly interpret floats etc. as coordinates, but as of now 4 does not.  Once you change it you will have to reindex your data, and it should be all set.